# How to calculate some fields using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to calculate some input fields using javasscript?
I'm really newbie at this so sorry if question was easy for you <3

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input name="price_1" id="price_1" value="5" type="text">
    <input name="pieces_1" id="pieces_1" type="text">
    <input name="subtot_1" id="subtot_1" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input name="price_2" id="price_2" value="7" type="text">
    <input name="pieces_2" id="pieces_2" type="text">
    <input name="subtot_2" id="subtot_2" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input name="price_3" id="price_3" value="9" type="text">
    <input name="pieces_3" id="pieces_3" type="text">
    <input name="subtot_3" id="subtot_3" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="total_price">21</td>
</tr>
```

Thank you everyone!

Comment: price1 * pieces1 + price2 * pieces2...

Comment: mat be you can use a grid control ...like jqgrid

Comment: Do you want a script to show the total price or just to calculate some fields? Your question is incomplete.

Comment: When should the calculations happen? Whenever the user tabs from one textbox to the next?

Comment: You've not given enough information. What exactly are you trying to calculate? What is the expected behavior? What have you tried already?

Comment: @Marcelo Rodovalho i need to show the price in each "subtot_" by keyup "pieces_" and additional i need the sum for all "subtot_" displayed in "total_price"

Comment: @SanelaB. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/5RDdM/ Edit: dt192 Already did it!

Answer (score 3):

Hi Sanela i've created a demo to help you out, it uses jQuery

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/L9PJa/

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input name="price_1" id="price_1" class="price" value="5" type="text">
    <input name="pieces_1" id="pieces_1" type="text" value="1">
    <input name="subtot_1" id="subtot_1" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input name="price_2" id="price_2" class="price" value="7" type="text">
    <input name="pieces_2" id="pieces_2" type="text" value="1">
    <input name="subtot_2" id="subtot_2" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input name="price_3" id="price_3" class="price" value="9" type="text">
    <input name="pieces_3" id="pieces_3" type="text" value="1">
    <input name="subtot_3" id="subtot_3" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="total_price"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" id="button" value="calculate"></td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  $('#total_price').text('0');
  $(".price").each(function() {
    $(this).next().next().val(parseInt($(this).val())*parseInt($(this).next().val()));
    $('#total_price').text(parseInt($('#total_price').text())+parseInt($(this).next().next().val()));
  });
});
```

on click for dynamically created elements

```
$("body").on("click", "#button", function() {
   $('#total_price').text('0');
   $(".price").each(function() {
      $(this).next().next().val(parseInt($(this).val())*parseInt($(this).next().val()));
      $('#total_price').text(parseInt($('#total_price').text())+parseInt($(this).next().next().val()));
   });
});
```

inputs not next to each other

```
$("body").on("click", "#button", function() {
   $('#total_price').text('0');
   $(".price").each(function() {
      $(this).next('input').next('input').val(parseInt($(this).val())*parseInt($(this).next('input').val()));
      $('#total_price').text(parseInt($('#total_price').text())+parseInt($(this).next('input').next('input').val()));
   });
});
```

Comment: awww.. thats very sweet of you. thanks a lot. will try that.

Comment: hmm. it won't work for my example. Maybe it is because i generate the html dynamically?

Comment: you can use the on method to bind instead 2 seconds... like that

Comment: hmm.. it wont work for my example :( do you need the url of my project to see what happens? drop me a message if.

Comment: yea sure post it ill have a look

Comment: can't post in public cuz its hidden project :|

Comment: oh ok mail me the link at daniel_tillin@hotmail.com

Comment: OK i think its just because in your webpage the inputs aren't right after each other as in the example given above, try the last code i posted here

Comment: I was just looking you already have code updating the subtotals on the page so my script doesn't need to do that all it needs to do is all the subtotals together, ill rewite something

Comment: It just gives me "NaN" return :(( But thank you for helping me

Comment: ok I've worked out whats happening, the other function you have that works out the subtotal is deleting the hidden input box when it over writes that table cell, so therefor the input box i'm referencing is no longer there

Comment: ok i've fully rewriten the other code you already had and merged it with mine check you email, all fully tested and working